# Nokia app for white balance

Tags: lumia

I want to edit white balance after I took a picture. Is it possible to do that with Nokia smart cam app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell this is not possible with Nokia Smart Cam. It can however be done with photo editing apps such as [White Balance Filter](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/white-balance-filter/42a754f6-3813-49be-8106-5df1cbe9e5b2).